# Can I set an alias in git for "pull --rebase"?

Tags: git, alias

I'm using git to create alias with this command:

```
git config --global alias.pr=pull --rebase
```

But it reminds me that:

```
error: invalid key: alias.pr=pull
```

I also tried:

```
git config --global alias.pr="pull --rebase"
git config --global alias.pr='pull --rebase'
```

But neither works.

What's the correct command for it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not use the equals character in your commands, and use quotation marks around the contents you want to provide an alias for, for example:

```
git config --global alias.pr 'pull --rebase'
```

Alternatively, you can set up your aliases by directly editing your `.gitconfig` file. See this **[link](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Aliases_with_arguments)** for further information on setting up aliases that include arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to always `rebase` when doing `pull`:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pull new revisions from remote branch, basically git is doing the merge and then fast forward. If you want rebase before the merge step you have to specify the following configuration in .git/config or your home git config file.

```
[branch "test-branch"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/test-branch
  rebase = true
```

So you have to specify the `rebase = true` option in whatever branch you want.